# Is it possible limit the number of emails sent for devise recoverable in a period of time for each user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-recoverable

Is it possible limit the number of emials sent for devise recoverable in a period of time for each user? How can I defend against malicious requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To limit: "emials sent for devise recoverable"

Example Gemfile:

```
gem 'simple_captcha2'
```

routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { ..., :passwords => 'passwords', ... }
```

app/controllers/passwords_controller.rb:

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
prepend_before_action :require_no_authentication
#
# GET /resource/password/new
def create
    if simple_captcha_valid?
        super
    else
        ....
    end
end
```

end

app/views/devise/passwords/new.html.erb
into the form_for:

```
<%= show_simple_captcha %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [grecaptcha](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha) to protect your form where you let the user rescue his account.

It's really easy and simple to use and include it in your rails app.

In your view:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= recaptcha_tags %>
<% end %>
```

In your controller, create action:

```
def create
  verify_recaptcha(model: @user) # => returns true or false
end
```

Comment: "views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb":
 <%= show_simple_captcha %>
and 
"controllers/registrations_controller.rb":
 if simple_captcha_valid?

But where will validate captcha if I write <%= show_simple_captcha %> into
 /devise/passwords/new.html.erb

Comment: You know how to do this: where can I validate captcha if I write <%= show_simple_captcha %> into /devise/passwords/new.html.erb. Thanks. The exampe in readme is very general